# How did Baba Yaga not become a Wight with a Humanity of 0?

Tags: world-of-darkness, npc, vampire-the-masquerade, morality-system

I found [Baba Yaga's character sheet](http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Baba_Yaga#Character_Sheet) on White Wolf Wikia. It says that she has Humanity of 0, and does not list her being on any Path of Enlightment. According to the rules, she would become a Wight in this case, while other parts of the article clearly state that she participated in some events which require sanity and being able to think.

How is that possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### The rules were different in First Edition.

The character sheet you're referencing dates to first edition *Vampire: the Masquerade* and *Werewolf: the Apocalypse* sourcebooks — **A World of Darkness** and **Rage across Russia**. Humanity 0 in those days could be used for sociopaths and the truly inhumane, rather than wights. You'll see anomalies like that all over the place in early books.

The most recent update to the character would be the tale of her death in **Nights of Prophecy.** Seeking that book out might give you a better impression of her stats in Revised.